# powershell script to sync sharepoint on premise environments

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, pnp-powershell

I'm after a script in powershell or if using PNP is easier to be able to have content databases etc..sync in different environments e.g dev,test

Any suggestions or tips would be appreciated